# Android Left Align Text In A NumberPicker

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying (and failing) to create a NumberPicker where the text is left aligned.

I've tried tinkering with the layout XML and in code but to no avail, it's always centred.

Here's my XML, can anyone advise what I need to change?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/numberPickerCancel"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonpress" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/numberPickerConfirm"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonpress" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried setting various layout:gravity, gravity and textAlignment attributes.

I've also tried setting ((EditText) view).setGravity() in code, this kind of works but only the selected element is aligned to the left.

Comment: did you try to set Gravity of edittext in onCreate method ? @W0035521

Comment: Yes tried that.  It's aligned to begin with but reverts to centered as soon as you change the selected value in the picker.